# Do historians use Rig Veda as a reliable source of historical event?

Tags: ancient-history, historiography, sources

[Rig veda](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigveda) is the oldest text in Hinduism, it is as old as 1500 BCE.

It contains many historical reference so, do historians use the historical accounts mentioned in the Rig Vedas as reliable sources of historical information or events?

"reliable "as a good source of historical information like. All the historical events mentioned in the Rig Veda happened in real life or they are mythology. Like battle of ten king, it is mentioned in the Rig Veda.

Comment: Reliable is subjective. Any source can be reliable, as long as you have context with it. For example, the New Testament can be considered reliable source of historical fact as long as you take into account what you are trying to ascertain vs. what was the mind set or the point the writer might have been embellishing on.  There's always a hint of truth in most sources, you just need to have the background to separate opinions, embellishments, or flat out lies. Even a lie can hint at some historical fact. Usually proves the antithesis of it. Can you be more specific as a source for what?

Comment: @EvanM as a good source of historical information like. All the historical events mentioned in the rig veda happened in real life or they are mythology. Like [battle of ten king](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_the_Ten_Kings#:~:text=The%20Battle%20of%20the%20Ten,formation%20of%20the%20Kuru%20polity.), it is mentioned in the rig veda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have read a lot of ancient Indian history and from what I have read Rig Veda is not considered a reliable source of history for historical events. Any ancient book to be considered as a reliable source of history must mention some event which is also known to have occurred from other sources. Rig Veda does not satisfy this criteria. Mostly books written after the Buddha period are considered reliable.

However, the Rig Veda is considered a very important source of cultural history of the Aryans. Especially religion and society.

Comment: Thanks of the answer